# How to set one column next to each other without space?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have this result actually

[image]

But I would like to have the blue text and total text next to button no matter what the resolution is, something like that:

[image]

I don't want to use col-md-x for example because its not the same space between, also tried float left on both elements inside a div but then I cant place them to the right, any solution?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <style type="text/css">
        .btn-custom {
            padding: 15px 25px 15px 25px;
            text-align: center;
            border-radius: 25px;
            -moz-border-radius: 25px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
            box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 0 rgba(63, 64, 64, 0.34);
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 0 rgba(63, 64, 64, 0.34);
            -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 0 rgba(63, 64, 64, 0.34);
            font-size: 14px;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-style: normal;
            font-stretch: normal;
            line-height: normal;
            letter-spacing: normal;
        }

        .bold-800 {
            font-weight: 800;
        }

        .container-custom {
            width: 80%;
            padding-right: 15px;
            padding-left: 15px;
            margin-right: auto;
            margin-left: auto;
            max-width: 1450px;
        }
    </style>
    <div class="container container-custom">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="accordion" id="accordion1">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header px-0" id="heading1">
                        <div class="row" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse1">
                            <div class="col-10 bold-800 md-paragraph">
                                Lore ipsum text header
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-2 text-right">
                                X
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="collapse1" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="heading1" data-parent="#accordion1">
                        <div class="card-body px-0 ">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-3">
                                    Lore ipsum text
                                </div>
                            
                                <div class="col-9">
                                    <div class="row mb-3">
                                        <div class="col-6">
                                            Lore ipsum + logo
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-6 text-right">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-6">
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="col-12 bold-800 text-primary">
                                                            133€ / persona
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-12 bold-600 text-custom-darker-grey">
                                                            Total 272€
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-6">
                                                    <button class="btn btn-custom bg-secondary bold-800" type="button">Reservar</button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try replacing `col-6` with `col-8` and `col-4` for the wrappers of the last two elements in the row. This is the result: https://nimb.ws/0H8dXI although I would try to design it with responsive classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give the column with the `button` the following value `class="col-auto"` and column with `content` `class="col"` and align your inner content to the right. This may help you